# Is it possible to override the CookieSupport configuration in the Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, areas

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with some Facebook integration using the Facebook C# SDK with cookie support switched on.

I had planned (and would still like) to create a canvas Facebook application as an Area of the main application. The problem is that canvas applications require that cookie support be turned off. Is there anyway to override this setting in the Area, or am I stuck?

**Update 11/01/2011**
I used the `location` node in web.config in order to override the `cookieSupport` setting.

```
 <location path="facebook">
  <facebookSettings
   appSecret="***"
   appId="***"
   cookieSupport="false" />

  <canvasSettings
   canvasPageUrl="http://apps.facebook.com/***/"
   canvasUrl="http://www.***.co.uk/facebook/"
   authorizeCancelUrl="http://apps.facebook.com/***/home/cancel" />
 </location>
```

It appears to authenticate users who have already authorised the app without issue. However users who're have not yet authorised do not get authenticated (they don't see the permission dialog).

I should stress that the configuration works as expected when the structure of the Area 'facebook' is put into an app of it's own.

Rich

Comment: It looks like I've been able to do it with the location node in web.config. Further testing will confirm this.

Comment: I hope someone can help me resolve this, I really didn't want to create a second application.

Comment: Looks like this could be MVC3 related.

Comment: It looks like aspects of this issue are being dealt as a bug between the Facebook C# SDK and MVC3 RC2. http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=240858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue somewhere between ASP.NET MVC3 RC2 and the Facebook C# SDK 4.1.1. See http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5794 for details.

The issue has since been resolved in version 4.2.1 of the SDK.

Rich

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can't do it via an area-specific web.config file, you could always just skip the settings in the web.config and set them manually:

```
    FacebookSettings facebookSettings = new FacebookSettings
    {
        AppId = yourAppId,
        AppSecret = yourSecret,
        BaseDomain = yourDomain,
        CookieSupport = false,
        MaxRetries = 2,
        RetryDelay = 500
    };
    var app = new FacebookApp(facebookSettings);
```

Comment: I think I'm trying to make the SDK do something it wasn't designed to. If I create a new project, the authorisation works as expected. If I apply the same settings to an area of an existing project, the area doesn't attempt to authorise.